# Recipe Database Design

Tags: database, database-design, architecture, many-to-many, schema

I am trying to create a database to store my recipes. However, I am not sure how to implement it. I looked at other questions like this but they do not have the same focus as I.

I assume any dish is actually just an ingredient, which can then be used in other dishes, or in this case in other ingredients. Any ingredient may have multiple recipes. For now, each recipe indicates how much of each ingredient is needed, but I also want to know how these ingredients are combined without having a long text description of it.

For example, in text, I would describe one (very bad) scrambled eggs recipes like this:

```
Scrambled eggs:
    Cooked for 5 minutes(
        1g Butter,
        Whisked(
            1g Salt,
            1g Pepper,
            2 Eggs
    )
```

and then `Scrambled eggs` could be used in another recipe as an ingredient.

But how would that translate in a database? I don't need that database to be SQL based since this is a personal project, but I don't know any other kind of databases so far.

I thought about defining an `Ingredient`, as having an optional `Technique` associated with it but that means `Whisked(1g salt, 1g pepper, 2 eggs)` would have to be an `Ingredient`. Which I guess could work and I could also make the name of ingredients optional, but it seems awkward.

I also thought about defining a `Recipe` as having multiple `TransformedIngredients` which would contain a `Technique` applied to many `Ingredients` but sometimes a `Recipe` contains raw, untransformed, `Ingredients` and sometimes `TransformedIngredients` would need to be applied to `TransformedIngredient`. From what I know of databases that wouldn't work.

PS: I stumbled onto a [functional programming Tiramisu recipe](http://www.lihaoyi.com/post/WhatsFunctionalProgrammingAllAbout.html#functional-programming-recipes) which, though very much focused on the techniques, displays fairly well what I'm trying to implement for my database.

Answer (score 2):

You can add some other fields to tables but I believe this schema works for you.

```
recipe
------------
r_id PK
recipe_name
cooking_time

recipe_of_recipes
-----------------
ror_id   PK
ror_name

recipe_ror (table for many to many relation-> defining a recipe as an ingredient)
-------------
r_ror_id PK
r_id     FK
ror_id   FK

ingredients
-------------
i_id     PK
t_id     FK
r_id     FK
ror_id   FK (added later)
ingredient_name
quantity

technique
-------------
t_id   PK
technique_name
```

### EDIT

Let's say you want to store a recipe (X) which is a combination of x and y recipes plus z ingredient.

To prepare X recipe (big X),

in `recipe`,`ingredients` and `technique` tables you store

- the x recipe and w,t,r ingredients with technique of p
- the y recipe and b,n,m ingredients with technique of v
- also z ingredient with technique of f (for this I forgot to add field ror_id as a FK in ingredients table)

You can define 2 different recipes (x and y) as ingredients of a recipe (X) using the `recipe_ror` table. This table relates to different recipes as one.(many to many relationship between tables `recipe` and `recipe_of_recipes`)

If you also want to store the technique for X,x or y recipes(like cook in your example), you can also add `t_id` field as FK to `recipe` and `recipe_of_recipes` table.

Comment: Could you explain that schema a little bit?

Answer (score 2):

I think what's confusing is that there are two different things to think about with a recipe, 'Items' and 'Steps'.

One database structure that comes to mind for this is a [Star Schema structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_schema) which separates these ideas nicely (into `Dimension` and `Fact` tables, respectively).

A quick description of each:

- Dimension

  - "The state of something" i.e. a record is merely there to describe what the thing is. A customer's address table would be an example of a dimension table.
- Fact

  - "Things changing over time" i.e. each record relates to a dimension table, but has changing values. An example would be shipped purchases from a website to a customer's address. The address stays the same, but the shipments are getting constantly added to the table.

This isn't to say that Dimension tables don't change, too; obviously new users sign up for websites all the time. In the above address example, if a customer were to change his address, a new `primary key` value would be added for the new address.

### Now on to your recipe examples:

Imagine you're cooking something. I would put anything that you hold in your hands in a "dimension" table. For example: `DIM_INGREDIENT` (with columns such as `INDREDIENT_ID`, `INGREDIENT_NAME`), and `DIM_AMOUNT` (`AMOUNT_ID`, `AMOUNT`, `UNITS`) to describe the amounts. And `DIM_ACTION` (`ACTION_ID`, `TYPE`, `LENGTH`, `UNITS`) to describe the action. There are more you can come up with; these are a few to get started.

Any steps I'd be taking could go in a `FACT_RECIPE_STEPS` table that would map to all the dimension tables. Any step that doesn't have a logical step would have a `null` value (i.e. stir for 5 minutes would have null for `INGREDIENT_ID`).

The `FACT_RECIPE_STEPS` could look like this:

`RECIPE_ID`, `RECIPE_STEP`, `ACTION_STEP_ID`, `INGREDIENT_ID`, `AMOUNT_ID`, `ACTION_ID`

What gets confusing is the "substep" of whisking the stuff together. I put that in another `FACT` table called `FCT_ACTION_STEP` since "whisking" is one action in the recipe list, but to perform the action you actually need to do three things.

### I think the following is what some of the tables would look like with your data:

```
DIM_INGREDIENT
INGREDIENT_ID: 1
INGREDIENT_NAME: 'Scrambled eggs'
INGREDIENT_ID: 2
INGREDIENT_NAME: 'Salt'
INGREDIENT_ID: 3
INGREDIENT_NAME: 'Pepper'
INGREDIENT_ID: 4
INGREDIENT_NAME: 'Eggs'
INGREDIENT_ID: 5
INGREDIENT_NAME: 'Butter'


DIM_ACTION
ACTION_ID: 1
TYPE: 'Cook'
LENGTH: 5
UNITS: 'minutes'
ACTION_ID: 2
TYPE: 'Whisk'
LENGTH: null
UNITS: null

FCT_ACTION_STEP
STEP_ID: 1
ACTION_ID: 2


DIM_AMOUNT
AMOUNT_ID: 1
AMOUNT: 1
UNITS: 'grams'
AMOUNT_ID: 2
AMOUNT: 2
UNITS: null


FACT_RECIPE_STEPS

RECIPE_ID, RECIPE_STEP, ACTION_STEP_ID, INGREDIENT_ID, AMOUNT_ID, ACTION_ID
```

EDIT:

I was a bit unsure myself as to how to do the "Whisked" part of the recipe and thought that, when you add the whisked mixture to the final result, it's like adding in one ingredient to the recipe. However, you need to prepare the mixture before and it has three steps. It's basically like it's own little recipe, and the `FACT_ACTION_STEP` takes that other 'recipe' into account to be able to add the result one row in the `FACT_RECIPE_STEPS` table.

Now that I think about it a bit more, it might be better to just assign "Whisked" as its own recipe in `FACT_RECIPE_STEPS` and `DIM_INGREDIENT` (called something like "Whisked spices for eggs") +and get rid of the `FACT_ACTION_STEP` table altogether. That way you can easily make more complex recipes, such as "Eggs and Pancake Breakfast" where the Eggs part is the result of this recipe.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what `FCT_ACTION_STEP` represents. I had never heard of the star schema though I'll look into it, thanks.